# Link problems with libc++abi when linking against libc++ via cmake

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, abi, libc++

I'm trying to build a simple ("hello world") `C++` program with LLVM/Clang 3.7.0 built from sources against the toolchain's `libc++`, with the command line:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-exceptions hello.cpp
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc++abi.so.1, needed by /bulk/workbench/llvm/3.7.0
/toolchain4/bin/../lib/libc++.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/bulk/workbench/llvm/3.7.0/toolchain4/bin/../lib/libc++.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow_primary_exception'
/bulk/workbench/llvm/3.7.0/toolchain4/bin/../lib/libc++.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_decrement_exception_refcount'
/bulk/workbench/llvm/3.7.0/toolchain4/bin/../lib/libc++.so: undefined reference to `std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'
[...]
```

The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is *not* set and the toolchain's install directory is added to my working `PATH` by:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bulk/workbench/llvm/3.7.0/toolchain4/bin/
```

I'm on `Ubuntu GNU/Linux 14.04` and I have not installed anything LLVM or Clang related packages from any repository.

According to the [libc++ documentation](http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-on-linux):

> On Linux libc++ can typically be used with only ‘-stdlib=libc++’. However some libc++ installations require the user manually link libc++abi themselves. If you are running into linker errors when using libc++ try adding ‘-lc++abi’ to the link line.

Doing as suggested gives a successful build.

*So, my question is this:*

Why do I have to specify the `-lc++abi` dependency explicitly on the line of the build command?

Doing

```
readelf -d $(llvm-config --libdir)/libc++.so
```

gives

```
Dynamic section at offset 0xb68c8 contains 31 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc++abi.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libc++.so.1]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x350a8
[...]
```

Shouldn't the embedded `RPATH` in the dynamic section of the ELF be considered by `ld` as described in its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) under the section `-rpath-link=dir`?

Moreover, when I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(llvm-config --libdir)
```

the initial build command (without specifying `-lc++abi`) works, as also described in the 5th clause of the aforementioned man entry.