# How to use llvm toolchain on Linux always by default

Tags: c++, linux, build, llvm

I'm trying to build linux docker image, that will use clang and llvm libs (compiler-rt, libunwind, libc++, ...) for build always by default. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304919/building-and-using-a-pure-llvm-toolchain-for-c-on-linux/47307984), but it uses CMake variables. I want to not have to make any edits to the projects themselves, so that llvm is always used by default. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Like using g++ .... `CXX=g++ cmake ..` or `CXX=g++-9 cmake ..`  is using llvm : `CXX=clang++ cmake ..`

Comment: @Knud Larsen It will use gcc stdlib anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build llvm with special flags ([full info](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html)):

```
-DLIBCXX_USE_COMPILER_RT=YES      # compiler-rt in libc++
-DLIBCXXABI_USE_LLVM_UNWINDER=YES # libunwind in libc++
-DCLANG_DEFAULT_CXX_STDLIB=libc++ # libc++ as std lib in clang by default
-DCLANG_DEFAULT_RTLIB=compiler-rt # compiler-rt in clang by default
```

And update cc/c++ links:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/clang 800 \ 
                    --slave /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/clang++
```